# ShouldProcess doing nothing once loaded into PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Simple case, trying to code a cmdlet that will prompt the user to confirm their action. This means I have to put [ShouldProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the ProcessRecord method call, but it always returns true no matter what (without prompting). Here's a simple case:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

[Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "ShouldProcess",
    SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
public class TestShouldProcessCommand : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0,
        ParameterSetName = "Force")]
    public SwitchParameter Force;

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        if (ShouldProcess("ShouldProcess Target"))
        {
            if (Force || ShouldContinue("ShouldContinue Query", 
                "ShouldContinue Caption"))
            {
                WriteObject("Hello");
            }
            else
            {
                ThrowTerminatingError(new ErrorRecord(new Exception(
                    "Error Message"), "Error ID", 
                    ErrorCategory.InvalidData, "Target Object"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you load up PowerShell and try to run it (after importing the dll using Import-Module) all you get is this:

```
PS C:\Users\user> Test-ShouldProcess

ShouldContinue Caption
ShouldContinue Query
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
Hello
```

This is the expected output for ShouldContinue, but nothing happens for the ShouldProcess call that comes first. If you just have it print out the return value of the ShouldProcess call, it's always true no matter how I use it. Tested in PowerShell 2 and 3, and on a vanilla machine. Using Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing the cmdlet with the common parameter `-WhatIf`.  That should cause `ShouldProcess()` to return false.  The idea is to show what the cmdlet would do without actually doing it when `-WhatIf` is used.  So you would want a more descriptive message in the `ShouldProcess()` call to indicate which pipeline object you're working on (assuming you support pipeline binding).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I hadn't realized that's how it was intended to work from the documentation, but I suppose it makes sense now. Thank you!